# Windows + Vim + Python2 + Python3 = Path nightmare

Tags: microsoft-windows, plugin-jedi-vim

I am using Vim 8.0.0326 64-bit from the [tuxproject](https://tuxproject.de/projects/vim/) with pathogen. I have 64-bit versions of Python installed in three locations:

1. Python 2.7 (64) - C:\Python27
2. Python 3.6 (64) - C:\Python36
3. Conda with Python 3.6 (64) - %APPDATA%..\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3

Only the Python 3.6 installed with conda is present in the path. If I check the python paths from within vim, I get the following for Python2:

```
:py import sys;print '\n'.join(sys.path)
C:\must>not&exist
C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip
C:\Python27\Lib
C:\Python27\DLLs
C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk
C:\Program Files\Vim
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages
_vim_path_
```

I don't understand how Vim is able to find Python27 since it is not in the path. I also don't understand where `C:\must>not&exist` is coming from. If I do the same thing for Python3:

```
:py3 import sys;print('\n'.join(sys.path)
C:\Users\akottke\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\python36.zip
C:\Python36\Lib
C:\Python36\DLLs
C:\Program Files\Vim
C:\Python36
C:\Python36\lib\site-packages
_vim_path_
```

Now Vim is finding both `C:\Python36` and the conda version. However, `C:\Users\akottke\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\python36.zip` doesn't actually exist, but `python36.dll` does.

The problem is that if I hide `C:\Python36` then Vim cannot run python3 even though it is in the path (provided by conda). This causes problems with library completion using jedi-vim.

How do I fix my path issues so that I can use jedi-vim to use Python3 provided by conda?